# How can I set the sonar-project.properties version dynamically to my latest git tag?

Tags: git, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, git-tag, sonarscanner

When launching SonarQube scanner from my terminal on my app, I would like the `version` in the `sonar-project.properties` to be linked to the latest git tag of my project, instead of setting it manually.

For example, if my latest tag is '1.2.0', launching the sonar scanner on my project should change its version to '1.2.0' if it wasn't already.

For now, to launch sonar-scanner on my project with a specific version, I do:

```
sonar-scanner -D version=1.2.0
```

How can I set the sonar-project.properties `version` prop to the latest git-tag of the project ?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do:

```
sonar-scannar -Dversion=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
```